# Wygwam and ExpressionEngine 3

Tags: wygwam, ee3

Are there any plans to upgrade Wygwam to be compatible with ExpressionEngine 3?

If not, any recommendations or issues on upgrading to EE3 and changing editors?

Thanks,
Carol

Answer (score 1):

According to Brandon Kelly, it is supposed to be on its way.

https://twitter.com/pixelandtonic/status/654257322189950976

I don't think they have a published road map for EE3 add-ons yet. Personally, I wouldn't start any new site with EE3 just yet, and every license you buy is active for EE2.10.1 for the time being. Anytime there is a left-of-the-dot change, there is a long period of uptake. They dropped CI as a core engine for EE, so it's possible there are a lot of little changes that make it harder to upgrade add-ons. Also, P&T (Brandon Kelly) is pretty busy with Craft CMS.

Check this list for EE3 compatible add-ons.

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/filter?&f=ee3

Also, Expresso is planing on an  early 2016 release of Expresso, a competing CKEditor based editor, for EE3.

https://www.putyourlightson.net/roadmap